# How to load an image in a QPixmap to display it in a QLabel

Tags: image, qt, qpixmap, qlabel

I've read multiple article on it and it still does'nt work!!

I know I'm doing it right, but for some reason it does'nt work.

Here's my code :

```
myIcon = new QLabel();
    QPixmap myPixmapForNow;
    if(!myPixmapForNow.load(":/img/Interrogation.png")){
        qWarning("Failed to load");
    }
    myIcon->setPixmap(myPixmapForNow);
```

It tells me that the file failed to load each time.

What i want to do with this is to display an image that will have a tooltip and explain what the button next to it does. Basicaly, I'm looking for a way to display an image that have a tooltip programmed in it.

I'm a beginner and honestly the concept of looking in folders is a bit abstract for me. If you have a blog or something to propose, i'll be willing to read it. I've been looking for one and I have'nt found any good one that explain the concept and how to do it.

If you have a solution for my problem please explain it. Nothing better than explanation :)

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I can see my generated resources.cpp and it has what appears to be the right stuff in it, however loading the pixmap always fails.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to do:

1. Check if `QFile` can open that resource and read it. Dump it out to a file on disk.

   ```
   QFile fi(":/img/Interrogation.png");
   QFile fo(QDir::homePath() + QDir::separator() + "Interrogation.png");
   if (!fi.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
     qWarning() << "Can't open the resource" << fi.fileName();
     return;
   }
   if (!fo.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
     qWarning() << "Can't open the output" << fo.fileName();
     return;
   }
   fo.write(fi.readAll());
   ```
2. Check the format of whatever is dumped out to disk to ensure that it's a valid png file. You can open it in an image editor, for example - just be sure to verify that the extension agrees with the contents. A valid JPEG file with `.png` extension will fail to load.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, I've reproduced your error. Probably, you are missed default prefix of resources that QtCreator usually sets up into `"/new/prefix1/"`. This string prefix must exist due to access resources. Try to modify your code within following way:

```
if(!myPixmapForNow.load(":/new/prefix1/img/Interrogation.png")){
```

Or, you need to discover your resource file to find out proper prefix string. If you had already modified prefix string then modify your code correspondently.